KMZ with Photo attachments in QGIS
So I have a KMZ file with a point layer and photos attached to each point. I'm wondering if there's a way to interact or display this in QGIS?
I can drag the KMZ into Google Earth and it displays my points and gives me a preview of the photo and its file name.
I'm processing data collected in the field and need to be able to get it into QGIS.

Could you provide test data? You do not need to share your coordinates and photos, you can you any other data instead. Only the structure of the KMZ/KML matters.
